# .Net Teams messaging extension bug

Tags: .net, microsoft-teams

I build teams extension in .Net. This is messaging action extenion.

Problem is when app return result of the action to Teams:

```
var heroCard = new HeroCard { Title = "Example", Text = "Example", };

return new MessagingExtensionActionResponse
{
    ComposeExtension = new MessagingExtensionResult
    {
        Type = "result",
        AttachmentLayout = "list",
        Attachments = new List<MessagingExtensionAttachment>()
        {
            new MessagingExtensionAttachment
            {
                Content = heroCard,
                ContentType = HeroCard.ContentType,
                Preview = heroCard.ToAttachment(),
            },
        },
    },
};
```

this card is visible in message box of each chats (not only in chat, from where I call bot).

Where is the problem?

Comment: Could you please share the repro steps or screenshots, so we can try it from our end?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/51.teams-messaging-extensions-action In this example is the same bug in "Share message" action. When I share one message in specific chat (with my friend for example), app return card with result. This card is visible in other chats in my Teams app.

Comment: We are able to repro that issue , We have raised bug for the same and concerned team is looking into it. We will inform you once we get any update. Thanks!